# Emacs elscreen - How to disable "split screen"?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've got elscreen on my emacs for tabbed windows but it's splitting my screen in 2 like so...

```
|-------|
|       |
|-------| 
|       |
|-------|
```

How would I make it only display one screen? The only things in my .emacs file is..

```
 135;; ---------------------------------------                                                                                                                 
 136;; load elscreen                                                                                                                                           
 137;; ---------------------------------------                                                                                                                 
 138(load "elscreen" "ElScreen" t)
 139
 140;; F9 creates a new elscreen, shift-F9 kills it                                                                                                            
 141(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t a b e") 'elscreen-create)
 142(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t a b d") 'elscreen-kill)
 143
 144;; Windowskey+PgUP/PgDown switches between elscreens                                                                                                       
 145(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-_") 'elscreen-previous)
 146(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-+") 'elscreen-next)
```

Also if it's relevant I installed elscreen via apt-get and I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Do you mean that `elscreen-create` splits the window, rather than replacing it? (If not, when?)

Comment: I hate the split screen that comes up by default. I am dying to know how to remove that.

Comment: Am doubting that is all that is in your .emacs, as you've got line numbers starting at 135.  Would also help to have Emacs version (`M-x emacs-version`).